# How would SQL Server combine Read-only and Write-only permissions?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Lets say I have two active directory groups:

- Database_RO
- Database_WO

Database_RO is granted DataReader rights.
Database_WO is granted DataWriter rights.

If a user is a member of both AD groups, is the user granted both DataReader and DataWriter rights?

I believe SQL will combine granted rights rather than going with the most restrictive, unless there is a explicit deny.   Correct?

Current SQL Server is 2012.   Will soon be migrating to 2016.

This question adds a corner case to the question it duplicates (two mutually exclusive AD groups rather than one group simply possessing additional rights), but the answer to that question answers that arrangement as well.

Comment: correct.  permissions are additive unless explicitly denied.  denied permissions overwrite explicit and implicit grants.

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate, the linked dupe question is about combining SA with Read_only while this question is about combing read and write access.